# trouble Installing ReportLab on python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I am currently trying to install  ReportLab on python 3.5 i have tried both "easy_install reportlab" and "pip install reportlab" and in both cases i get the error message [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat ]. Would really appreciate trouble shooting hints for this problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Search SO for that error message or just 'vcvarsall.bat' and if that does not work, try Google.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it's a broken package.
Try to install reportlab using pip

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall reportlab
```

Then you need to restart idle or pycharm ..etc